# Beginner problems using templates for a custom sorting algorithm in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying do to a templated collection of functions for std vectors of several value types.

So I started with a sorting algorithm and did it like this:

```
template <typename T>

struct SortReturn{
    std::vector<T> values;
    IntVector indexes;
};

class FunctionCollection
{
public:
    FunctionCollection();

    static SortReturn<T> QuickSort(std::vector<T>, bool ascending = true);

private:

    static SortReturn QuickSortRecursive(SortReturn array, int left, int right, bool ascending);

};
```

However this does not compile and it gives me

/home/ariela/ownCloud/Workspace/FunctionDev/functioncollection.h:18: error: 'T' was not declared in this scope
     static SortReturn QuickSort(std::vector, bool ascending = true);
                       ^

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it probably helps more if you start with a tutorial or guide on templates instead of just getting a simple answer which points out the mistake here.

Comment: The template refers only to the first structure. The second structure (a class) is also templated, and needs its own template definition.But you'll need a lot more before you have your own functional sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you'll need to template both your struct and class, you'll also need to pass your `SortReturn`  object to `QuickSortRecursive` with it's templated type as well as return the object with it's templated type, the code should look something like

```
template <typename T>
struct SortReturn{
    std::vector<T> values;
    IntVector indexes;
};

template <typename T>
class FunctionCollection
{
public:
    FunctionCollection();

    static SortReturn<T> QuickSort(std::vector<T>, bool ascending = true);

private:

    static SortReturn<T> QuickSortRecursive(SortReturn<T> array, int left, int right, bool ascending);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

A `template <…>` declaration only holds for the next item, e.g. the next function, struct, or class declaration/definition.

Therefore, you need to add a second one before `FunctionCollection`:

```
template <typename T>
class FunctionCollection
{
  …
```

Also, you need to add `T` to your `SortReturn` in your parameters and return types.

That being said, you're misusing a class for a (private) namespace. Since templates need to be defined in a header either way, put the implementation in a namespace like `detail` or `internal`:

```
template <typename T>
struct SortReturn{
    std::vector<T> values;
    IntVector indexes;
};

namespace internal {
    template <typename T>
    SortReturn<T> QuickSortRecursive(std::vector<T> array, int left, int right, bool ascending){
        …
    }
}


template <typename T>
SortReturn<T> QuickSort(std::vector<T> arr, bool ascending = true) {
    return internal::QuickSortRecursive(arr, 0, arr.size(), ascending);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was beginning to realize this.